# App permission granted but not able to generate token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to use Facebook attribute API because it seems I don't have the `attribution_read` permission.  When I am going on my App Review section, I can see I was granted the `attribution_read` as "read to use".

[image]

However, when I am going under Products --> Marketing API --> Tools. I can not generate an access token with the `attribution_read` permission.

[image]

When I am doing an API call with the `Attribution API` with `ads_read, read_insights and ads_management` permissions selected, this is the response:
[image]

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/?ids=<BUSINESS_UNIT_ID>&fields=ad_platforms.order_by([%7B%22direction%22:%22asc%22,%22field%22:%22name%22%7D]).filter_by(%7B%22is_archived%22:false%7D).limit(3).count(1).summary(1)%7Bconnection_details,external_import_file,connection_type,created_date,custom_tags,id,is_archived,last_modified_by%7Bid,name%7D,last_modified_date,live_status,name,platform_type,setup_progress%7D&access_token=<MY-TOKEN>
```

Comment: Have you tried generating an access token from within Graph API Explorer?

Comment: Now works! Amazing thanks.Do you know where I can find documentation on the Attribution API? The official documentation for this API is just a list of 5-6 examples

Comment: If by official documentation you are referring to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/attribution, then no.

Comment: Ok great thanks. Do you know if the Attribution API can be used with a  Python SDK? My request is going to be pretty long and I would need to write it using Python